# Mysql join: Where to put the condition that goes on the right table?

Tags: mysql

I read somewhere that the condition on the right table(j.jobStatus="A") must place before the where clause.

Is there a difference betwen 1) and 2)?

1)

```
SELECT c.cmpID
FROM company AS c
LEFT JOIN jobs AS j ON c.jobID=j.jobID
WHERE j.jobStatus="A" AND c.cmID > 10
```

2)

```
SELECT c.cmpID
FROM company AS c
LEFT JOIN jobs AS j ON c.jobID=j.jobID AND j.jobStatus="A"
WHERE c.cmID > 10
```

Comment: There is no such requirement.  Both queries are correct and will produce the same result.  Most likely, they will also run in the same amount of time. Try `EXPLAIN`ing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that `WHERE j.jobStatus = "A"` nullifies the `LEFT JOIN`, essentially making it an `INNER JOIN`.  Any rows where j would be NULL are filtered out by that condition.

If the condition is on the `ON` clause, it still allows `NULL` rows to be returned for the jobs table (i.e. rows in the company table that do not have a matching row in the jobs table).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. What you said make sense.